# Is this way a good one to build a plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I was just wondering if the following way is a good one for building a jQuery plugin and if not which are the best practices:

```
$.fn.loginsys = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.loginsys.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        /* Code To Be Executed */

    });

}

$.fn.loginsys.defaults = {

    /* Some Options */

}
```

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to change the default options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggestm this from jquery tutorial plugin (but there are several way):

```
(function($) 
{   
    var globalSettings=
    {
        width:400,
        height:400
    };

    var methods =
    {
        init : function(options)
        {
            return this.each(function() 
            {
                var $this=$(this);
                var settings=$.extend({}, globalSettings, options);

                //your code

            });
        },
        destroy : function()
        {
            return this.each(function()
            {

            });
        },
        option : function(option, value)
        {

            if(value!=null && value!=undefined)
            {
                return this.each(function(){
                    var $this=$(this);
                    var curr_setts=$this.data('settings');
                    curr_setts[option]=value;
                    $this.data('settings',curr_setts);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var $this=$(this);
                var curr_setts=$this.data('settings');
                return curr_setts[option];
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.siter=function(method, options) 
    {
        if(methods[method])
        {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
        else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method)
        {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        else
        {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery');
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Opening braces should never be put on new lines to avoid automatic semicolon insertion (--> premature termination of multiline statements/declarations). Plus, it's ugly.

Comment: you are really old, there are several way of writing code and this, in my opinion, is the most readable way. it has also a particular name

Comment: I have a question regarding this way of writing a plugin, I have found in other plugins something like this `jQuery.fn.reverse = Array.prototype.reverse;` at the beginning of it, what does that stand for ?

Comment: it seems to be a array conversion method, a minimal demo Array.prototype.reverse is a function and the plugin reverse does exactly what this function do

Answer (score 4):

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

  };
})( jQuery );
```

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

Best practice and everything aside, is there a reason for wanting to expose the defaults?

If you want them to be editable from the outside you may want to expose a setter for that instead and keep them inside of the $.fn.loginsys = function closure, so as to make sure they can't be fiddled with in a way that would stop your plugin from working.

See jQuery's ajaxSettings() for example.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, is @albanx code example a good idea and can the options be edited outside the plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the wrapper

```
(function($) {

    // plugin code here

})(jQuery);
```

But, there are many plugin patterns out there; here are a [bunch of templates](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns) available for downloading.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look over all the templates :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several good tutorials on how to write jQuery plugins, like http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/. Just google a bit. Also, take a look at how other jQuery plugins are constructed. That's where you can learn the most I think.